# Sorting an Applescript list in ascending order by indexing

Tags: list, sorting, applescript

I am trying to sort a list of file names in a created from one folder. Here is the code as it's simplest form. If I run this the 10 always comes after the 1 rather then the 9. What am I over looking.

```
set composer_list to {"Filename_1", "Filename_2", "Filename_3", "Filename_4", "Filename_5", "Filename_6", "Filename_7", "Filename_8", "Filename_9", "Filename_10", "Filename_11"}
simple_sort(composer_list)


--======================================= Sorting Handler =====================================
on simple_sort(my_list)
    set the index_list to {}
    set the sorted_list to {}
    repeat (the number of items in my_list) times
        set the low_item to ""
        repeat with i from 1 to (number of items in my_list)
            if i is not in the index_list then
                set this_item to item i of my_list as text
                if the low_item is "" then
                    set the low_item to this_item
                    set the low_item_index to i
                else if this_item comes before the low_item then
                    set the low_item to this_item
                    set the low_item_index to i
                end if
            end if
        end repeat
        set the end of sorted_list to the low_item
        set the end of the index_list to the low_item_index
    end repeat
    return the sorted_list
end simple_sort
```

Result:

```
{"Filename_1", "Filename_10", "Filename_11", "Filename_2", "Filename_3", "Filename_4", "Filename_5", "Filename_6", "Filename_7", "Filename_8", "Filename_9"}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use:

```
considering numeric strings
    simple_sort(composer_list)
end considering
```

Result:

```
{"Filename_1", "Filename_2", ..., "Filename_9", "Filename_10", "Filename_11"}
```

Answer (score 2):

However, one variant to this problem that I had:

I had a list with hyphenated sections and subsections, using numbers separated by hyphens (section1, section1-3, section1-3-5, section2-0). Using the original simple_sort, 1-3-5 was coming in before 1-3. However, using "considering numeric strings" instead treated the hyphens as minus signs, and things were all jumbled. However, I added another subroutine to pre-treat the compared strings by removing the hypens before comparing:

```
on removeHyphens(theText)
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "-"
set theReturn to every text item of theText
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
set theReturn to theReturn as string
return theReturn
end removeHyphens
```

Then in the simple_sort function, I changed one line to this:
    else if removeHyphens(this_item) comes before removeHyphens(low_item) then

This worked like a charm for this specific circumstance.

Answer (score 1):

It's because

```
"Filename_11" comes before "Filename_2" -- true
```

If you zero pad the list, it should work.

```
"Filename_11" comes before "Filename_02" -- false
```

You should [download Nigel Garvey's "A Dose of Sorts"](http://mac.softpedia.com/get/Utilities/A-Dose-of-Sorts.shtml) for the best sorting routines.

Answer (score 0):

how about 
ignoring hyphen
...
end ignoring

but the best answer is: use Filename_01 (leading 0 padding)